# Running Emacs on tmux startup

Tags: tmux

I'm trying to get the hang of tmux, but can't figure out how to bring it up and start an emacs session with that session in the foreground.

I have this in my tmux.conf

**new 'emacs -nw**

and I can see an emacs session when I press prefix-W and see a number of windows and I can select it then, but I'd like to go directly to it when tmux starts up.

I admit I'm a tmux newbie and don't yet understand the difference between new neww or whether I should start with a 'tmux attach'.

It's all very confusing to me. Most of the videos seem to show how to create/split windows/panes but not much attention seems to be applied to configuration options.

My tmux.conf contains

new 'emacs -nw'

I want my emacs session to be the focus when starting tmux, but it doesn't appear in focus.